# How to deduce type from a reference as constructor parameter?

Tags: c++

How could I deduce the vector's type automatically from the reference
without having to specify it?

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct CopiedVector {
    std::vector<T> v;
    CopiedVector(std::vector<T>& v_to_copy_from)
    {
        size_t v_to_copy_from_size=(v_to_copy_from).size();
        v.resize(v_to_copy_from_size);
        for (size_t i{0}; i != v_to_copy_from_size; ++i)
            v[i] = (v_to_copy_from)[i];
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vct1{-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    CopiedVector<int> vct2(vct1); //this is the line where i have to specify <int>
    for (size_t i = 0; i != vct2.v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vct2.v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

(I know it's no-sense to write such this struct, but it's for learning/experimenting purposes only)

Comment: This is very simple: upgrade your compiler so that it supports the C++17 standard. Then -- in this case -- you don't need to specify the template parameter. I just verified, and after adding the missing `#include`, gcc compiles `CopiedVector vct2(vct1);` just fine, in C++17 mode.

Comment: This is called [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and works in c++17 and forward.

Comment: For C++17, you may need a deduction guide. `template<class T> CopiedVector(std::vector<T> const&) -> CopiedVector<T>;`  I also assumed you want the constructor parameter to be `const`, since the parameter isn't being mutated.

Comment: Raymond Chen recently posted an excellent article about this problem https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220420-00/?p=106506